# Как в ansible узнать содержимое текстового файла лежащего на сервере без модуля shell?

Tags: linux, bash, администрирование, virtualbox, ansible

У меня есть плейбук, который ставит последнюю версию Виртуалбокса. Для этого надо дёрнуть текстовый файл и считать с него содержимое. Текущая реализация выглядит так и нормально работает:

```
- local_action: shell wget -O - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/LATEST-STABLE.TXT
  register: virtualbox_latest_version
```

Но ansible ругается, что это не Ъ и надо пользоваться модулем `get_url`. Всё бы хорошо, но я [не нашёл](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/get_url_module.html) где там параметр эквивалентный wget'овскому `-O -`.

Comment: Если нет аналога, значит выкачиваете, а затем читаете файл этим: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/lookup/file.html

Comment: @imsysmem, этот путь я рассматривал. Он очевидный и больший по коду, я думал, что есть более изящный вариант.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965199/ansible-wget-then-exec-scripts-get-url-equivalent То есть нет красивого решения.

Comment: Думаю таги linux/bash/администрирование/virtualbox тут излишни, вопрос 100% по Ansible :)

Comment: @Hellseher, это для тупого будущего меня, когда захочу вспомнить что чё-то там было про линукс и вбокс. Впрочем, если модераторы решат, что тегов много - сопротивляться не буду.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пробуйте `uri`

```
- hosts: self
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: "test uri"
      uri:
        url: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/LATEST-STABLE.TXT
        return_content: yes
      register: check_me

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ check_me.content }}"
```

Результат:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "5.2.20\n"
}
```

Из интересного в `uri` можно общаться непосредственно с HTTP/S сервисами и он стабильный `This module is flagged as stableinterface`

---

**UPD**

Ansible это build-in Jinja+Python, логика та же, разбиваем по новой строке, берем первый элемент или просто заменяем все '\n' на что то еще.

```
- debug:
    msg: "split: {{ check_me.content.split('\n')[0] }}"

- debug:
    msg: "replace: {{ check_me.content | replace('\n', '') }}"
```

Результат один и то же:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "split: 5.2.22"
}

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "replace: 5.2.22"
}
```

---

**UPD2**

Полная рабочая версия выглядит так:

```
- local_action:
    module: uri
    url: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/LATEST-STABLE.TXT
    return_content: yes
  register: virtualbox_latest_version
- debug:
    msg: "{{ virtualbox_latest_version.content | replace('\n', '') }}"
  register: virtualbox_latest_version
- debug:
    msg: "{{ virtualbox_latest_version.msg }}"
```

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html
- http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#replace
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Афигенно, а как убрать `\n`? Я шаманил с `lineinfile` но не понял как скормить ему не файл. Куда копнуть?

Comment: @donRumata   просто мыслите как если бы это был просто Python  скритп, обновил ответ. Кстати версия VB обновилась с момента первого варианта ответа :)

Comment: Если бы я умел Питон, то я бы на нём мыслил. Но я чуть-чуть умею баш и ещё меньше cmd\powershell (последний вообще очень мало). Так что тут сложно.

Comment: Да, виртуалбокс (и кучу прог) для винды качаю как раз через баш. Вполне работает.

Comment: Добавил версию "под ключ", надеюсь, ты не против.